# Shell script which parses .tex files for figures

Tags: parsing, workflow, awk

I would like to pull all figures including captions out of multiple `.tex` files and write them into a single new `.tex` file. This means I have to parse for

```
\begin{figure}
   . . . 
\end{figure}
```

and output that whole block. I have no clue about regular expressions, but I think `grep`or `awk`are best suited for this task. Can anyone help me out with the parsing-part? Writing a bash script to do the rest is no problem for me.

Comment: `\usepackage{endfloat}` will do it for you, writing a `filename.fff` file containing exactly what you need.

Comment: Related/Possible answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89972/11002

Comment: @egreg, amazing! I tried it now and the file `fff` contains `\begin{figure*}` even if I use non stared environment.

Comment: @Sigur I would suppose that it is a "feature": you don't want one- and two- column floats mixed in the end ;)

Comment: `\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{endfloat}

\begin{document}
Foo 

\begin{figure}[h]insert here\caption{bla}\end{figure}

Foo
\end{document}` returns *File ended while scanning use of \next*.

Comment: @Sigur The package requires that `\end{figure}` is on a line by itself and starting at column 1, which isn't so bad a requirement. You *don't* indent all your `document` environment, do you?

Comment: @egreg, how could I imagine this? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but I like neither egregs, nor thoeczs packages... They both throw error messages and do not work as I wish. I think I'm going to write a little python script which does the trick. My question still stands, though...

Comment: It seems like both suggestions satisfy the requirements of the question.  If they don't, then could you be more specific about how they fail/in what way they don't meet your needs.  Perhaps provide a MWE and the structure of the desired output.

Comment: They work absolutely fine in a simpler setup, but I have a quite complicated setup of my LaTeX documents with many packages. My idea was that approaching this from 'outside LaTeX' is the easier way, hence my question for using awk or grep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** @deimi 's answer at [Compile only the theorems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180606/compile-only-the-theorems) using the `xcomment` package might make this awk script unnecessary.

Here's an `awk` solution that bypasses `TeX` parsing.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
# Extract figure environments
#

BEGIN{
    printing = 0;
}

/begin\{figure/{
    printing = 1;
}

printing == 1 {
    print;
}

/end\{figure/{
    printing = 0;
}
```

Comment: I was writing exactly the same answer! A note, your (and my) solution assumes that there is no `figure` environments inside, for example, verbatim blocks which should not be output, and that no extraneous chars are at the beginning of the line with `\begin{figure}` or at the end of the line with `\end{figure}`, which should be stripped

Comment: Please, post also your solution! :)

Comment: @JLDiaz My solution does work even when characters precede or follow the `begin{figure` or `end{figure` patterns. It just prints the whole line in each case. The OP can strip that extra stuff if he wants to. Yes, I output figures inside `verbatim` - probably rare, and fixable if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

My original answer was to be the following script, totally equivalent to the answer by Ethan Bolker, which posted when I was writing it.

```
/.*begin{figure}/{
    output=1
}
output==1{
    print
}
/.*end{figure}/{
    output=0
    print "% ---------------------------------- "
}
```

I cancelled my answer, but the OP asked me to post it nevertheless, so here it is.

In order to provide some added value, I'll post also the following variation, which deals with some rare cases (not really needed, I implemented it only for fun), in particular:

- It strips extraneous chars which could appear at the beginning of `\begin{figure}` or the end of `\end{figure}`
- It does not output `figure` environments inside `verbatim`, `Verbatim` or `lstlisting`.

```
BEGIN{
    in_verbatim=0
}
/.*begin.(verbatim|Verbatim|lstlisting)/{
    in_verbatim=1
}
/.*end.(verbatim|Verbatim|lstlisting)/{
    in_verbatim=0
}
/.*begin.figure./{
    if (! in_verbatim) {
        output=1
        split($0, aux, "begin{figure}")
        print "\\begin{figure}" aux[2]
    }
    next
}
/.*end.figure./{
    output=0
    if (! in_verbatim) {
       split($0, aux, "end{figure}")
       print aux[1] "end{figure}"
       print "% ---------------------------------- "
   }
}
output==1{
    print
}
```