# Compile only the theorems

Tags: theorems

Is there a way (package or anything) to compile only the theorems in a tex-document. With theorems I mean the lemmas, propositions and theorems defined in the theorem-environment of the amsthm package. I would like to have a list of the results to see the underlying structure better.

Comment: You could redefine the theorem/lemma/etc. environments to write their content to a new file.

Comment: An option could be the `preview` package, but you get a page for each environment you declare to be included in the preview.

Comment: The answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91188/shell-script-which-parses-tex-files-for-figures/91203#91203 implements @HenriMenke 's idea using `awk` rather than  redefinitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `xcomment` package:

```
\usepackage{xcomment}
\xcomment{theorem,lemma,defn}% list environments you want to print 
\begin{document}
```

Comment: This is a very easy solution. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the package [optional](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/optional/optional.pdf). There you can define passages that are optional.