# Reprint all equations in specific environment

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I have a long document with many equations, theorems, definitions, etc. They are in different environments, e.g. for definitions I have

```
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{definition}
...
\end{defintion}
```

What I want to do is make a document where I just have all the definitions (things that appear in the definition environment) that appear in my main file, with none of the other text. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Depending on your needs, there maybe several potential ways to arrive at what you need. The simplest is using `xcomment` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180606/compile-only-the-theorems); however, if your definitions have more complicated numbering (for example, if the definitions share a counter with another environment, or if the definitions are numbered within each section), then the numbering generated from the `xcomment` solution will not match the original.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes unfortunately they are numbered by chapters and sections.

Comment: I encourage you to edit all details (precise formatting requirement etc) into the question, because solutions will depend on them. Specifically, what could help is for you to try the `xcomment` solution mentioned, and record a list of things that are unsatisfactory and what the desired outcome should be. If the only issue is with the numbering within chapters and sections, it probably isn't too hard to fix (one just needs to make `xcomment` aware of `\chapter` and `\section`, which looking at the source file should not require too huge a change).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define the `definition` environment so that it calls the “real” one after grabbing the text that can be saved in an auxiliary file to be input by another file.

The write out operation is done after the typesetting, so we can use `\thedefinitioninner`, which will have the correct value.

### Main file `bedge.tex`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definitioninner}{Definition}[section]

\ExplSyntaxOn

% the definition environment grabs the environments
% contents, including possibly the optional argument
\NewDocumentEnvironment{definition}{o +b}
 {
  \bedge_definition:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
 {}

% allocate a stream for writing the definition texts
\iow_new:N \g_bedge_definition_iow
% and open it
\iow_open:Nn \g_bedge_definition_iow { \c_sys_jobname_str.defn }
% and close it at the end
\AtEndDocument{\iow_close:N \g_bedge_definition_iow}

% the main command
\cs_new_protected:Nn \bedge_definition:nn
 {% typeset the definition and then write the contents
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #1 }
   {% no optional argument
    \begin{definitioninner} #2 \end{definitioninner}
    \__bedge_definition_write:en { \thedefinitioninner } { #2 }
   }
   {% optional argument
    \begin{definitioninner}[#1] #2 \end{definitioninner}
    \__bedge_definition_write:enn { \thedefinitioninner } { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

% no optional argument
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__bedge_definition_write:nn
 {
  \iow_now:Nn \g_bedge_definition_iow { \saveddefinition{#1}{#2} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__bedge_definition_write:nn { e }

% optional argument
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__bedge_definition_write:nnn
 {
  \iow_now:Nn \g_bedge_definition_iow { \saveddefinition{#1}[#2]{#3} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__bedge_definition_write:nnn { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}

\section{Test}

\begin{definition}
This is an unnamed definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[Foo]
This is a named definition.
\end{definition}

\section{Another}

\begin{definition}[Foo]
This is a named definition.
\end{definition}

\chapter{Second}

\section{Test}

\begin{definition}
This is an unnamed definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[Foo]
This is a named definition.
\end{definition}

\section{Another}

\begin{definition}[Foo]
This is a named definition.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

### Secondary file `bedge-defn.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition \thisdefinitionnumber}
\newcommand{\thisdefinitionnumber}{} % initialize

\NewDocumentCommand{\saveddefinition}{m o +m}{%
  \renewcommand{\thisdefinitionnumber}{#1}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {\begin{definition}#3\end{definition}}
   {\begin{definition}[#2]#3\end{definition}}%
}

\begin{document}

All the definitions in the main document follow.

\bigskip

\input{bedge.defn}

\end{document}
```

If I run LaTeX on the first file, a file called `bedge.defn` will be produced (the name is the same as the first file's)

```
\saveddefinition {1.1.1}{This is an unnamed definition.}
\saveddefinition {1.1.2}[Foo]{This is a named definition.}
\saveddefinition {1.2.1}[Foo]{This is a named definition.}
\saveddefinition {2.1.1}{This is an unnamed definition.}
\saveddefinition {2.1.2}[Foo]{This is a named definition.}
\saveddefinition {2.2.1}[Foo]{This is a named definition.}
```

The result of running LaTeX on the secondary file is

[image]